# SSMS 2016 Status bar -no option to see session id

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016

I am using SSMS 2016 version.

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      13.0.16106.4
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools                    13.0.1700.441
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     10.0.14393.0
Microsoft MSXML                                             3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                                 9.11.14393.0
Microsoft .NET Framework                                    4.0.30319.42000
Operating System                                            6.3.14393
```

In previous version I was able to see session id at the status bar or tab text.
I could navigate to Tools-->Options-->XML-->Editor Tab and Status Bar and turn it on of off.  I do not see the same in SSMS 2016.

Anybody know if this option is removed or relocated under other option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it. It was hidden due to long name of my instance and userId.  Once I hover the cursor on top I could see it. Here is a screenshot.
[image]